# how does Haskell code works without applying the parameter?

Tags: haskell

I encountered the following Haskell code:

```
trafficController :: Double -> Picture
trafficController t
 | round (t/3) `mod` 2 == 0 = trafficLight True
 | otherwise                = trafficLight False

main :: IO ()
main = animationOf trafficController
```

I ran and it worked. But how can it be coz the 't' parameter was never applied ?

Comment: Surely `animationOf` implementation applies it somewhere.

Comment: Functions are first-class values: they can be passed as arguments, returned as results, put into pairs/lists/other containers, etc. You do not have to apply a function immediately each time you mention it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `t` parameter is indeed never applied explicitly. However, you are correct in saying that `trafficController` needs `t` to be applied in order to work. What gives?

In this case, the `animationOf` function is the key. Let’s have a look at its type:

```hs
animationOf :: (Double -> Picture) -> IO ()
```

We can see that `animationOf` takes a function as its first parameter. Presumably, the implementation of `animationOf` takes this function, figures out the correct `Double` to use, applies this value to the function, and then draws the resulting `Picture` on the screen. (Since this is an animation, it probably does this multiple times.) So even though you never apply the parameter explicitly, `animationOf` does it for you.